# awk & sed split file

Tags: bash, sed, awk

if I have a file test.txt:

```
example 1 content 2013-3-8:
hello java
example 2 content 2013-4-9:
hello c
```

how can I use awk or sed to seperate the test.txt to two file

test1

```
hello java
```

test2

```
hello c
```

I use the command below:

```
awk '/example/{i++}{print > "test"i}' test.txt
```

but it will remain the first line(example xxx), can I add some fragment to the **print** in awk to delete the first line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You almost have it:

```
awk '/^example/ { i++; next } { print >"test"i}'
```

the `next` makes `awk` skip the rest of the statements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`getline`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline) to skip the first line.  The following should give the desired output:

```
awk '/example/{getline; i++}{print > "test"i}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Some weird way of doing this with sed:

```
sh <<< $(sed '/example/{N;s/\n//;s/example \([0-9]*\).*:\(.*\)/echo "\2" >> test\1;/}' input)
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ne '2~4w test1.txt' -e '4~4w test2.txt' test0.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like :

```
awk 'BEGIN {i=0; j=0} /example/{i++; j=0} (j != 0){print > "test"i} {j++}' test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "
/example 1/ {N;s/^.*\n//
   w test1.txt
   }
/example 2/ {N;s/^.*\n//
   w test2.txt
   }" test.txt
```

if you define a delimiter between section (define size or marker), there could be more text to put in each file

Answer (score 0):

To complete the response from Alok Singhal: if you reach the "too many open files" limit on linux, you have to close the files in line.

```
awk '/^example/ {close("test" i); i++; next } { print >"test" i}'
```